# Amazon S3 PHP : Getting confirmation of successful copyObject

Tags: php, amazon-s3

Using the SDK AWS for PHP. I'm transfering a file from a bucket to another one with this :

```
$s3->copyObject([
            'Bucket'     => $targetBucket,
            'Key'        => "{$targetKeyname}",
            'CopySource' => "{$sourceBucket}/{$sourceKeyname}",
        ]);
```

It works fine but I can't figure out how to know if the transfer request has been successful.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you

Comment: Check for a `CopyObjectResult` in the response of that. [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#copyobject-example-1)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't find much about CopyObjectResult . I ended up using S3Exception .

Comment: @Chuck use `$result = $s3->copyObject(...` then examine `$result`.  Avoid calling in void context.